# no sound at all

Tags: sound, lenovo, alsa

No sound at all...

Checked all the drivers and sound card, all are installed properly. Checked through the ubuntu forms but the old solution(adding the option snd-hda-model to lenovo sky in alsa.conf)  is not working. My internal audio devices are showing(also in pulse audio control). There is no error being shown. Also if i plug in headphones, there is a little sound that plays but not understandable, just beats and that too unclear.

This is Lenovo Ideapad Y510 -2008 model and is running only on Ubuntu 13.10

```
drivers: ALC888

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3d96
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at feaf8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Also tried Wyth's solution http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=870681&page=15        but its old i guess, and all my drivers are already the right. and `sudo alsa force-reload` isn't working either.

here's complete information http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1cc118fa827da3bcc019a712f8ed827f1d71d8de

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.62
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sat Feb  8 08:01:47 UTC 2014


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 13.10 \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      LENOVO
Product Name:      INVALID   
Product Version:   Lenovo IdeaPad Y510
Firmware Version:  06CN23WW


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    3.11.0-12-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      i686
Processor:         i686
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k3.11.0-12-generic
Library version:    1.0.27.2
Utilities version:  1.0.27.1


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel'
```

Comment: Can you boot from a live CD and get sound - just to prove that the hardware is OK? Did it work before and what did you do since then that might have broken it?

Comment: Has similar problem. Sound works  just fine on Windows, but no sounds on ubuntu at all.